# wget apache kafka not working

Tags: debian, wget

I have Debian 32bit installed and I am using the Terminal (no GUI).

I would like to install [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads), so I am doing:

```
wget https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.12-1.0.0.tgz
```

But the thing I am getting is a file called:

```
closer.cgi?path=/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.12-1.0.0.tgz
```

That doesn't look right to me, plus the download finishes instantly, which makes me suspicious that something isn't right.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you run `file` on it? It's possible it is still the correct file but is named improperly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You took the wrong link, you had to click on it first : the good one is

```
http://www-us.apache.org/dist/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.12-1.0.0.tgz
```

(found [here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.12-1.0.0.tgz) )
=>

```
wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/kafka/1.0.0/kafka_2.12-1.0.0.tgz
```

will download kafka 1.0.0